# how to get the map type pointer in c++, map

Tags: c++, pointers, types, stl, dictionary

I want to write something to share memory, 
pAttr is the share memory address.

The template function as below,
but it does not pass the compile.

```
template <typename Container>
int ShareMemMgn::writeContainerToShareMemMap(void* pAttr, Container& oData)
{
    typename Container::mapped_type T;
    (T*)(pElem) = (T *)(pAttr); //compile errror
/*
share_mem_mgn.cpp:545: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
share_mem_mgn.cpp:545: error: ‘pElem’ was not declared in this scope
share_mem_mgn.cpp:545: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token

*/


    for(typename Container::iterator it = oData.begin();
        it != oData.end(); ++it)
    {
        memcpy(pElem, (&(it->second)), sizeof(typename Container::mapped_type));
        ++pElem;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

How to get the maped type pointer?
Could anyone help me?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also do this

```
template <typename KeyType, typename ValueType>
int ShareMemMgn::writeContainerToShareMemMap(void* pAttr, std::map<KeyType,ValueType>& oData)
```

If you are using only a Map.

Comment: Yup, I'm going to change my function prototype as your advice, if I will not get any suggestion. Good for me, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

As your code reads right now, `T` is a variable, not a type.  Presumably you meant this:

```
typedef typename Container::mapped_type T;
T * pElem = static_cast<T *>(pAttr);
```

Comment: thanks, it works. but not the static_cast reason. (T*)(pElem) is not right, if I changed to "T * pElem", it pass. Thanks a lot, cdhowie!

Comment: @lear Correct; I fixed both issues.  You should not use C-style casts in C++, so I corrected the cast operator as well.